# How can I retrieve only filtered records in a Child Model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table that I want to use to show records of timesheet logs, I've been able to do a filter using whereHas which works, but when I try to filter by employee I still get the logs for all employees attribtued to those jobs instead of the one I'm searching for.

My controller:

```php
$request = json_decode(json_encode($request->all(), true))->params;

$jobs = Job::whereHas('timesheets', function($query) use ($request) {
    if (count($request->selected_employees) > 0) {
        $query->wherein('employee_id', $request->selected_employees);
    }
    if (count($request->selected_clients) > 0) {
        $query->wherein('client_id', $request->selected_clients);
    }
    if (!empty($request->start_date)) {
        $query->where('date','>=',$request->start_date);
    }
    if (!empty($request->end_date)) {
        $query->where('date','<=',$request->end_date);
    }
});

$jobs = (new Job)->generateReport($jobs->get(), $request->selected_employees);

$result = array_merge_recursive($jobs);

return $result;
```

My Model which iterates through the job. So far everything is accurate except for the child relationship called 'timesheets', it's not defined here, but laravel auto populates it and I am not able to overwrite/replace anything with that attribute. Any ideas?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Job extends Model

{
    use HasFactory;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ["client_id", "job_number", "job_date", "payment_type", "rate", "description"];

public $totalHoursArray = array();
/**
 * @var array|mixed
 */
private $report_totals;

public function client() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}

public function timesheets() {
    return $this->hasMany(TimesheetLog::class);
}


public function creator(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'created_by');
}

public function editor(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'edited_by');
}


/**
 *
 * Returns a count of Employee Hours per job for timesheet entries
 * currently selected in the Job model
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getEmployeeHoursPerJob($employee_ids){

    $i = 0;
    $hours_per_job = array();
    $timesheets = empty($employee_ids) ? $this->timesheets : $this->timesheets->whereIn('employee_id',$employee_ids);

    foreach ( $timesheets as $trow) {
        $trow->employee_code = Employee::find($trow->employee_id)->code;
        $date = new \DateTime($trow->date);
        $trow->date = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');

        //find if the employee exists in the hours per job array if not, push a new row
        $found = array_search($trow->employee_id,array_column($hours_per_job, 'employee_id', isset($hours_per_job['employee_id']) ? 'employee_id' : null));

        if($i > 0 && $found !== false){
            $hours_per_job[$found]['total_time'] += $trow->total_time;
        } else {
            array_push($hours_per_job, ['employee_id' => $trow->employee_id, 'employee_code' => $trow->employee_code, 'total_time' => ($trow->total_time)]);
        }

        $i++;
    }

    return $hours_per_job;
}

public function generateReport($jobs, Array $employee_ids){

    $report_totals = array();
    $filtered_timesheets = array();

    foreach ($jobs AS $jobrow) {
        $i = 0;

        $jobrow->client_name = Client::find($jobrow->client_id)->name;
        $jobrow->attention = Client::find($jobrow->client_id)->attention;
        $jobrow->rate = "$".$jobrow->rate ." ". $jobrow->payment_type;

        $dateT = new \DateTime($jobrow->job_date);
        $jobrow->job_date = date_format($dateT, 'd-m-Y');

        $hours = $jobrow->getEmployeeHoursPerJob($employee_ids);
        $jobrow->employee_hours = $hours;


        foreach ($filtered_timesheets as $timesheetf){
            array_push($timesheets_filtered, $timesheetf);
        }

        foreach($hours AS $hoursRow){

            $found = array_search($hoursRow['employee_id'],array_column($report_totals, 'employee_id',
                                        isset($report_totals['employee_id']) ? 'employee_id' : null));


            if($found !== false){
                $report_totals[$found]['total_time'] += $hoursRow['total_time'];
            } else {
                array_push($report_totals, $hoursRow);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return compact('jobs','report_totals');
}



}
```

In the foreach loop I assigned a new property of the row to a wherein query and this was accurate and what I wanted. But again, I couldn't replace or assign the original property that I want to send to the view.

```php
$jobrow->timesheets_filtered = $jobrow->timesheets->wherein('employee_id',$employee_ids)->toArray();
```

Comment: Please, post the contents of the `Job` model

Comment: @JonathanMartins posted.